# How to read xxx bytes from a file, output to variable(s)

Tags: file, variables, batch-file, split, sequential

Im trying to split a file into sequential pages that are 8159 bytes long. How can i read 8159 bytes of a file and save to the all!count! var? if the file is 8159 or less it reads the file and sets it to the !all! variable. How in the :split label can i read only so many bytes and save to variable.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ("newhtml.html") do set FileSize=%%~za
echo FileSize is %FileSize% bytes
if %FileSize% GTR 8159 goto split

SETLOCAL DisableDelayedExpansion 
set "all="
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`"findstr /n ^^ newhtml.html"`) do (
    set "line=%%a"
    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "line=!line:#=#S!"
    set "line=!line:*:=!"
    for /F "delims=" %%p in ("!all!#L!line!") do (
        ENDLOCAL
        set "all=%%p"
    )
)
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
if defined all (
set "all=!all:~2!"
set ^"all=!all:#L=^
[blank line, remove this comment]
[blank line, remove this comment]   
!"
set "all=!all:#S=#!"
)
echo the all variable is: !all!
goto end

:split
set count=0
set /a all_sub=%FileSize% / 8159
set /a all_rem=%FileSize% %% 8159
if %all_rem% NEQ 0 set /a all_ttl=%all_sub% + 1
echo %all_sub% full page(s), %all_rem% bytes(s) leftover, %all_ttl% total pages

for  %%a in ("newhtml.html") do (
    set /a count=count + 1
    echo Read 8159 bytes from this file newhtml.html, save to all!count!
    if !count! EQU %all_ttl% echo All done & goto end
)

goto end

:end
```

the section that needs help is the split label, and in the for loop that reads the file, how to get only 8159 bytes of data at a a time and write to sequential variables. i guess that i should make the !all! a function and then call it?

edit: i found this file (http://www.fourmilab.ch/splits/) to do the splits, short work to add it to the ALL routine to reassemble. many thanks dbenham and jeb!

Comment: Using batch to load the contents of a text file into an Oracle CLOB is going to be very painful. If you can get the file on your server and you are friends with the DBA, then Oracle has tools that can make the task simple. Oracle can open the file directly and populate the CLOB with a small bit of programming. It can also be done on the client side via Java, C++, VB etc. I've seen conflicting reports as to whether client JavaScript can establish an Oracle connection directly. If it can, then JScript might be a good option. Perhaps this question should be redirected to the Oracle community.

Comment: I'm not sure why I'm assuming Oracle. Most of what I said in my prior comment is probably true with most any relational database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply read the file into an *array*?
Each line would be one entry this works, if there isn't any line with more than ~8190 characters.
Then you didn't need the replacing tricks for the linefeed and so on.

But this depends of your actual problem.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL DisableDelayedExpansion
set "all="
set count=0
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`"findstr /n ^^ aux1.txt"`) do (
    set "line=%%a"
    set /a count+=1
    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "line=!line:*:=!"
    for /F "delims=" %%p in (^"set "array[!count!]=!line!"^") do (
        ENDLOCAL
        %%p
    )
)

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /L %%n in (1 1 %count%) do (
  echo Line%%n:!array[%%n]!
)
```

Comment: i thought the single line limit was 1023 (somewhere?)i tested the routine when newhtml.html was 8159, it read the html file into the !all! variable just fine. even one byte over and it would chop the file. so im using a dos program called chunk to break it up into 8159 segments, then i can read into each variable. remember that this is a html source file which contains ! among other special characters. but let me play with your routine to see if it works on larger files. many thanks Jeb!

Comment: Yes and no, 1023 if you read a file with `set/p`, 2048 for drag and drop, 8192 for a "normal" line, unlimited (>10MB) if folding(_expansion_) reduces the result under 8192.  And ~8190 is the limit for one variable, but the variable space is nearly unlimited (Dave?)

Comment: so that worked! no suprise there. but how do i get the file into a single variable (which has limit of ~8K). essentially what im trying to do is read a html file (of any size, up to 50kb) into a variable(s) so that i can then use the variable(s) in an sql query. so i prime the vars for the sql script, then echo it to a sql file which executes script and puts newhtml.html file into sql record. can i use what you have to do that?   also, couldnt i use find /v /n "" instead of findstr, that way i get [#] and not #:, as the ] is easier to parse. ideas?

Comment: i think there is a 65K limit on the env stack for all total variables. maybe someone could chime in on that, if so that would mean that i could only have 8 pages of 8k data, correct?

Comment: not 8 pages, but 8 variables of 8k data, that would be concurrently. could always dip into setlocal to fix that though.

Comment: No, I believe dbenham, Aacini and Ed made some perfomance tests with variables using some/many megabytes, somewhere at dostips.com. But each single variable can't contain more that ~8190 bytes. And for your sql-problem ... ask a new question

Comment: I agree with jeb. I believe there is a limit with true DOS, but true DOS is rarely used now. If the Windows command environment has a limit, it is very large. Megabytes of storage is definitely supported, I suspect much more.

Comment: well yes i am using windows cmd.exe to run with the variables. but i just tested several files of various sizes and ~8190 bytes is the limit in one var, any more and it just drops the information.so i made the program to slice and dice the html but having logic problem with reassembly. can you guys look at it at comment?